# Supero (Haskell supercompiler) usage?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

I'm having a look at this project http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/supero/

I have downloaded and compiled the program, and could use it on the included samples. But I tried it on my source code and it looks like the program only understands a subset of Haskell.

I got something like this:

> supercompiler: Unhandled fromDecl: PatBind (SrcLoc {srcFilename =
>   "unknown.hs", srcLine = 15, srcColumn = 1}) (PTuple [PVar (Ident
>   "width"),PVar (Ident "height")]) Nothing (UnGuardedRhs (Tuple [Lit
>   (Int 7),Lit (Int 6)])) (BDecls [])

The code is available here https://github.com/phuc/Score4-haskell/blob/master/Main.hs

How do I get GHC to outputs the kind of Haskell that Supero understands?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The slides [here](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/downloads/slides-haskell_with_go_faster_stripes-30_nov_2006.pdf) seem to suggest that it is first run through Yhc, then transformed into an intermediate form HILL (First order Haskell Intermediate Little Language
 - see slides), and then, finally, the analysis can be done.

Another slideshow provides this diagram:

[image: Diagram of Compilation Process]

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the current version of Supero only handles a subset of Haskell described in the [ICFP 2010](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/downloads/paper-rethinking_supercompilation-29_sep_2010.pdf) paper.

The previous version did integrate with the YHC pipeline and could handle a larger subset. This was quite a while back and the compilation of YHC itself is pretty soul destroying. I wouldn't recommend it.

[Max Bolingbroke](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mb566/) is currently integrating his own supercompiler into GHC. However, I can't see the code on his [GitHub](https://github.com/batterseapower/chsc) repository so it might not yet be ready for public consumption.

Comment: There is a `supercomilation` branch in the GHC repo though.